# Relationship between the ranks of matrices $A$ and $B$ , where $B$ is obtained by changing one element of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $5 \times 5$ matrix and let $B$ be obtained by changing one element of $A$. Let $r$ and $s$ be the ranks of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Which of the following statement is/are correct?

1. $s \leq r + 1$
2. $r - 1 \leq s$
3. $s = r - 1$
4. $s$ is not equal to $r$

I don't know how to start. For me it seems like all options are correct as when we are changing only one element then anything can happen. The rank can increase/decrease by 1 or remain same.
But the correct answer is 1 & 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice 1. and 2. combine together to get $r-1\leq s\leq r+1$. See if you can convince yourself that no matter what happens, changing one element of $A$ can only increase or decrease the rank by at most $1$, or leave it unchanged. Look at, for instance, the rowspace.

Comment: It might be useful to recall that we can think of the rank of a matrix as the dimension of its column space. What happens to the span of a set of vectors when we modify one of the vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statements $3$ and $4$ can be true ***but not always true***. For example, let $A = I_5$, the $5 \times 5$ identity matrix, and 
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $s = r = 5$, negating the statements $3$ and $4$.

To show that statements $1$ and $2$ are correct, note by definition, if $\text{rank}(M) = r$, then $M$'s every $(r + 1) \times (r + 1)$ submatrix 's determinant is $0$ and at least one of $M$'s $r \times r$ submatrix's determinant is nonzero.

Hence $s > r + 1$ would imply that there exists an $(r + 2) \times (r + 2)$ submatrix $B'$ of $B$ such that $\det(B') \neq 0$. This would lead to contradiction since if we expand $\det(B')$ along the column (or row) containing the element changed by $A$, then $\det(B') = 0$, in view of every determinant of $A$'s $(r + 1) \times (r + 1)$ submatrix is $0$.

In a similar manner, we can show that statement $2$ is also true.